# Translating C# code for ZMQ socket polling to F#

Tags: f#, zeromq, c#-to-f#

My question concerns translating to F# the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800252/zeromq-clrzmq4-polling-issue) stackoverflow question. I am using the [ZeroMQ C# CLR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZeroMQ/) package.

Here is part of the C# (from the answer to the linked post):

```
ZSocket[] sockets = { receiver1, receiver2 };

ZPollItem[] pollItems = { ZPollItem.CreateReceiver(), ZPollItem.CreateReceiver() };

ZError error;
ZMessage[] msg;

while (true)
{
    if (sockets.PollIn(pollItems, out msg, out error, timeout))
    {
        if (msg[0] != null)
        {
            // The first message gotten from receiver1
        }

        if (msg[1] != null)
        {
            // The second message gotten from receiver2
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt at the translation:

```
let ctx = new ZeroMQ.ZContext()

let sub1 = new ZeroMQ.ZSocket(ctx, ZeroMQ.ZSocketType.SUB)
sub1.SubscribeAll()
sub1.Connect("tcp://localhost:3001")

let sub2 = new ZeroMQ.ZSocket(ctx, ZeroMQ.ZSocketType.SUB)
sub2.SubscribeAll()
sub2.Connect("tcp://localhost:3002")

let timeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10.)
let sockets = [|sub1; sub2|]
let pollItems = [|ZeroMQ.ZPollItem.CreateReceiver(); ZeroMQ.ZPollItem.CreateReceiver()|]

let mutable error = ZeroMQ.ZError
let mutable msg = Array.init<ZeroMQ.ZMessage> 2    // ??? C#:  ZMessage[] msg;

while true do

    if ZeroMQ.ZPollItems.PollIn(pollItems, &msg, &error, timeout) then   // no overloads match
        if msg.[0] <> null then
            () // work

        if msg.[1] <> null then
            () // work

    ()
```

Maybe the no overload error on the PollIn method line resolves if the `ZMessage[] msg` is properly defined in F#. I think the library itself is besides the point but happy to provide further details if needed. My main problem is I don't understand C# and barely understand F#.

Comment: The items separator for collections in F# is `;`, not `,`. `sockets` and `pollItems` are currently lists of 2-tuples of their respective types, which is not what you want.

Comment: error and message appear to be out parameters in the C# code. If that's the case define them as mutable, or pattern match on them. E.g. `let  mutable error = ZeroMQ.Zerror` and then call it it `.PollIn(.., &msg, &error, timeout)` or `let msg, error` = .Pollin(pollItems, timeout)`. Not familiar with ZMQ so can't test it...

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev Thanks, fixed the commas.

Comment: @s952163 Made the edits but I'm not exactly sure what ZMessage[] msg is.

Comment: That just declares the `msg` variable to be of type `ZMessage array`. The left side of `Double[] x = new Double[3] { 1.0,2.0,3.0 };`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using but here's a hint: `[1; 2; 3]` is a list of ints, `[|1; 2; 3|]` is an _array_ of ints. There is a difference.

Comment: @professorbigglesworth do you just need an empty ZMessage array?  `let mutable msg = Array.empty<ZMessage>`

Comment: @s952163 Hmmm... How do I initialize something like let mutable msg = Array.init<ZeroMQ.ZMessage> 2 (fun i -> ????) . The msg object holds 2 items, the first of which is checked for a null.

Comment: And as Jeff Mercado hints maybe it's better to use an Array as a container, and not an F# list. In C# the type signature `int []` is an array of ints. And actually that's the type signature you get in F# as well if you define an Array of ints like [|1;2;3|]. That array is a .NET array, so can be used in C# and F#. However just using [1;2;3] will give you an F# list, which is something specific to F#, with type signature `int list`.

Comment: Indeed, changed to arrays. A couple of days in another language at work and I'm totally blanking on F# now.

Comment: @professorbigglesworth  You shouldn't work in any other language :D Regarding your Array syntax, you don't need anything fancy to create it since you're just initiliazing it. How about `let mutable msg = Array.zeroCreate<ZeroMQ.ZMessage> 2`

Comment: @s952163 Hahaha, I completely agree. I think the declarations all look fine to me now but the PollIn method is still unhappy. Going to sleep on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler wrote - there is no such overload. Just look at what the function expects to receive:

1. You forgot to specify the socket as the first parameter.
2. Timeout must be of type Nullable:

So...

```
open ZeroMQ
open System

let ctx = new ZContext()

let sub1 = new ZSocket(ctx, ZSocketType.SUB)
sub1.SubscribeAll()
sub1.Connect("tcp://localhost:3001")

let sub2 = new ZSocket(ctx, ZSocketType.SUB)
sub2.SubscribeAll()
sub2.Connect("tcp://localhost:3002")

let timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10.) |> Nullable
let sockets = [|sub1; sub2|]
let pollItems = [|ZPollItem.CreateReceiver(); ZPollItem.CreateReceiver()|]

let mutable error = null
let mutable msg = null 

while true do

    if ZPollItems.PollIn(sockets, pollItems, &msg, &error, timeout) then 
        if msg.[0] <> null then
            () // work

        if msg.[1] <> null then
            () // work

    ()
```